# Github branches showing up different latest tags for different branches

Tags: git

In my GitHub repo, I have been using master/main branch to create tags for releasing purpose, but recently due to some merge complications I had to create a new branch 'release-branch' and create tags from this branch and do the release.

For master branch when I run below command I am getting the last tag created from master branch.

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
4.9.0
```

For my release branch when I run same command I am getting tag created from that brach

```
5.0.0
```

My question first question is, is this approach correct ? Or have I messed up my tagging process? And how can I make my tag `5.0.0` attached/associated to master branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git describe` always takes the nearest *reachable* tag. Merge your `release-branch` into master and the tags on your release-branch become reachable from master too.

```
A-B-T1-C-D     < master
   \
    `-E-T2-F   < release
```

From `master`, `T1` is the only reachable tag. `T2` is only reachable from release.

Now, if you merge with `git checkout master && git merge release`, `T2` becomes reachable from master too:

```
A-B-T1-C-D---M     < master
   \        /
    `-E-T2-F       < release
```

Comment: So immediately after creating tag from release branch, I should merge it back to master ?

Comment: @NikhilKumar that depends on what you want your history to be. If it is a requirement that the tags are reachable from master, then you must merge them (or their child commits) into master

Comment: @NikhilKumar: knittl has given a good description of the inner workings of `git describe`. It looks like you have a need to identify "the version of my project". See if "runnig `git describe --tags --abbrev-ref=0`" is a good fit for your need, or if you need to get that information in some other way.

Comment: For example : getting "the highest tag version in all of my repo" can be something like `git tag --list --sort=version:refname | grep -e '^[0-9.]*$' | tail -1` (list all tags, sort names as numbers if they look like version numbers, keep only version numbers, keep the latest one)

Comment: Or perhaps you just need to take into account `master` and `release`, and keep the highest of the two. or ...